# How to show the url of the items in a SharePoint document library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have a bunch of images in the sharpeoint document folder. I would like to create a column that can give URLs of every item in that folder. I have tried to export the file to excel in SharePoint and tried to run the macro that can fetch the URLs but macro-enabled files are not working in SharePoint. Could you please help me with any easy way out to get the URLs? please check the below image. I have items in the folder, all I need is another column with the URL of every item.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a flow to show the url of all items in a SharePoint document library:

[image]

Result(Per my test I updated the title column, you could update the column for your requirement):

[image]

Comment: This worked Julie, thank you. The only change I made was to select drop down as Yes in the nested items field.

Comment: If you find any reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as answer.